# Django server error

Tags: python, django

I can't seem to figure out why I started to get the server error listed all of a sudden.  Any ideas?

The full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 221, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 66, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 286, in get_traceback_html
    c = Context(self.get_traceback_data())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 244, in get_traceback_data
    frames = self.get_traceback_frames()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 390, in get_traceback_frames
    pre_context_lineno, pre_context, context_line, post_context = self._get_lines_from_file(filename, lineno, 7, loader,
 module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 371, in _get_lines_from_file
    context_line = source[lineno].strip('\n')
IndexError: list index out of range
[01/Nov/2012 10:46:55] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 221, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 66, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 286, in get_traceback_html
    c = Context(self.get_traceback_data())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 244, in get_traceback_data
    frames = self.get_traceback_frames()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 390, in get_traceback_frames
    pre_context_lineno, pre_context, context_line, post_context = self._get_lines_from_file(filename, lineno, 7, loader,
 module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 371, in _get_lines_from_file
    context_line = source[lineno].strip('\n')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally got it figured out... I set debug = False, just to see what would happen because the traceback included debug.py.  Anyway, I'm still a beginner, and don't even know if this really even makes sense, but after I changed debug = False in my settings, I got a new traceback which informed me that one of my CHOICES in one of my forms didn't match. I don't understand at all why this would crash the development server, but I fixed it and now it works.  So to clarify what the problem was:

```
#forms.py

PAYMENT_PLAN = {
    ('A', 'A'),
    ('B', 'B'),
    ('C', 'C'),
}

class SurveyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        widgets = {
            'pay_plan': Select(choices=PAY_PLAN),
            ...
        }
```

So, the new traceback with debug=False stated:

```
NameError: name 'PAY_PLAN' is not defined
```

So anyway, I fixed that, and now it works again.  So if someone runs into the same issue, try turning debug=False to see what happens and maybe it will help you figure it out.

Comment: I still appreciate the earlier attempt to help me from jro, even though it wasn't really successful.

Comment: No worries, glad you figured it out. For some reason I still suspect something funky is going on in your sources (or maybe your Django installation). The debugger tries to find the troublesome source files, and format them nicely so that you can more easily find the issue. Disabling the debug flag skips this process, and gives you the raw traceback, hence allowing you to see what's going wrong. If you are still curious, you could try removing all .pyc files from your Django site package... that might help as well, and could be convenient if want to use the debug flag again.

Comment: Oh, also, be sure to accept your own answer if it resolved your issues.

Comment: Thanks again. I turned debug back to true after I corrected that issue stated above, and it has been working since.  I hadn't tried removing all the .pyc files from my Django site package, just from my project, so it is good to know in case it occurs again, and I will give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell if you are using a webserver of any kind, or just the development server. In any case, shutdown any server you are using, and clean up all of the .pyc files in your project. Restart the webserver, and you should be good to go.

Most commonly there is a mismatch between the compiled files and the sources. As to why this happens, no clue, but it has happened to me in the past: doing the above resolved it for me.

Comment: I appreciate the advice.  I tried it, but unfortunately, no luck.  I am just using the development server currently.

Comment: Another thing to try (assuming you use a version control system (and if not, shame on you ;)) is to clone/fork/copy your latest revision to a different directory, and see if it works then. Or, do a clean check out of an older revision. If any of these work, your problem was still most likely related to some leftovers in your source tree.

Comment: So could the error be resulting from something in my code somewhere, or is there another possible solution? I am still not having any luck.

Comment: I started a new project and moved everything into that project; still no luck.